# Bash: passing multiple files to a function/program when fuzzy search for paths is available

Tags: bash, loops

I am trying to do the following , say there is a list of files like so

```
/folder1/subfolder1/*.ext1  /folder2/subfolder2/*.ext1 /folder3/subfolder3/*.ext1
```

and assume the command is supposed to be

```
Package -fileset <the above files> > output
```

The program right now fails to locate the files given the paths directly (i.e, if I issue the command like this)

```
Package -fileset /folder1/subfolder1/*.ext1  /folder2/subfolder2/*.ext1 /folder3/subfolder3/*.ext1 > output
```

but has no trouble when I use a for loop and do for i in  and then supply $i as an argument.

What is the best way to be able to go from a path search to supplying multiple files to the command simultaneously?

Comment: Are you sure your program supports multiple files on the command line?  The for loop would feed files one at a time to the command, which would bypass that limitation (if there is such a limitation)

Comment: yes I am - I have applied it before with multiple files simultaneously, but the advantage was having the files in the same folder and the full paths available rather than fuzzy search results. 

Each of the files would be a BAM file in the following command http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/multicov.html